# What are the reasons UnMerge will not work in Access VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, merge

I have a VBA macro in Access 2016 (actually, written for earlier version, but right now I'm working with 2016). What it does is adjusting several Excel spreadsheets, and moving them to another location, while also writing some logs into SQL table.

One of adjustments is unmerging some merged cells. The weird part is, those excel files fail to process at times (not always), when this Access DB is triggered programmatically (from another macro in another Access DB). When I launch it manually, or go into debug step-by-step, it always works - so I am confused, and can't find the reason.

I tried to replace "MergeCells = False" for "Unmerge" - it's the same. I also tried to make new ACCDE file - no result.

This is part of the code, where the unmerging occurs.

```
xlsh.Select
xlsh.Range("A1:D1").Select
xlsh.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
With Selection
    .UnMerge
End With
xlsh.Range("A1").Value = "Alfa"
xlsh.Range("B1").Value = "Bravo"
xlsh.Range("C1").Value = "Golf"
xlsh.Range("D1").Value = "Tango"
xlsh.Range("A1").Select
If xlsh.Range("A1").Value = "" Then GoTo error
```

When it fails to unmerge the cell, the value won't get assigned, and at the end it's empty, thus, continues to label 'error'.

Comment: You haven't properly qualified the `Selecction` object, but you shouldn't need to use it anyway - just use: `xlsh.Range("A1:D1").Unmerge`

Comment: Using an unqualified `Selection` like this outside Excel VBA will also lead to other unexpected results, e.g. code that runs the first time, but not the second time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
xlsh.("A1:D1").Unmerge
```

Instead of

```
xlsh.Select
xlsh.Range("A1:D1").Select
xlsh.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
With Selection
    .UnMerge
End With
```

The last 2 lines are unnecesary as:

```
If xlsh.Range("A1").Value = "" Then GoTo error
```

Will not be true as you are assigning a value a few lines before. (`xlsh.Range("A1").Value = "Alfa"`)